# Is there a simple way to map error responses back to exceptions in RESTEasy client?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I have mapped exceptions to http responses on server side with JAX-RS exception mapper. On Java client side I'd like to map those responses back to reasonable exceptions. I'm using RESTEasy proxy client framework with shared interfaces across client and server. I'd like to avoid wrapping all invocations in try catch. I'm rather looking for inversed exception mapper.
Looking for something like ResponseExceptionMapper from CXF but for RESTEasy.

Comment: I'm not sure that throwing an exception on the client is a reasonable approach.  There's no exceptional condition occurring on the client, other than a message being provided to you which you can display to the user, or take some other action on.

Comment: The client jar is passed to other teams. They just call Java methods instead of working on HTTP layer. They'd like to have different exception thrown if the server is down or they passed wrong arguments or there is a security exception. Now it's WebApplicationException each time.

Comment: Do you get an error code back?  Check the error code and rethrow the proper exception.  I know you're looking for the easy way to do this, but I doubt there's a "reverse exception mapper" if you haven't already found one.  You don't need to check every error code, only the ones that you need to differentiate.

Comment: I guess I'd just wrap the services proxies in another proxy. Thanks.